# Не могу понять как сделать спавн блоков на реакте

Tags: java, html, css, reactjs, create-react-app

При нажатии на кнопку должен спавниться блок образца `<div>kjkjkj</div>` в другом каком-либо блоке. Как это вообще делается?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Первое что прихоит на ум это сделать состояние внутри родителького компонента для кнопки и генерируемого блока, и поставить условие что при изменение этого состояния(которое будет менятся при клике на кнопку) должен появлятся блок который нужен